# Why am I getting a "A communication error occurred" querying an as/400 server?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a site that queries an as/400 database for certain peices of information, including one small peice of info on the logged in user.

Because of this, the as/400 is queried whenever a user is logged to a fresh session.

I'm getting sporadic reports of a `A communication error occurred` server error, especially when people login on the weekends.

If you hit f5 and refresh the page the error clears and everything works great.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

I was thinking that since f5 clears the error that I could simply retry any query that failed for this reason, but I don't want to start without a deeper understanding of the situation.

I've gone through IBM's user docs and quite of bit of google searching and haven't come up with anything.

*edit*

The connection is made with the `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries` drivers for windows, version 12.

The connection code looks something like:

```
public DataSet RetrieveDataSet(string sql)
 {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    iDB2Connection con = new iDB2Connection();

    iDB2DataAdapter da = null;
    try
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;

        con.Open();

        da = new iDB2DataAdapter(sql, con);

        da.Fill(ds);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)//yes i am aware this should not be catching the base exception
    {
        LogError("AS400Connection", "RetrieveAll", ex.Message, sql, ex.StackTrace, con.JobName.Trim());
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        if(da!=null)
            da.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
        ds.Dispose();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

The `da.Fill(...)` line is throwing the Communication Error exception.

Comment: What programming language are you using? How are you connection to the system? Can we maybe get a sample of the code that is the problem area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just writing a small peice of code that attemped a small query just before each critical section, so if the job was ended it only kills that query instead of the whole app.

Edit -

The "CheckConnectionOnOpen" connection string parameter does essential the same thing, but as part of the driver.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you had to create a work-around, but stability is key over efficiency sometimes.

Comment: In this case, it was time frame. ><

Answer (score 1):

A very common scenario is TCP/IP connections are silently shutdown by network routers and firewalls when being idle for a long time.

I would guess that this is exactly what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... that is a weird one. Have you been able to duplicate the error? If you don't get any other suggestions here, maybe try putting this on one of the [midrange.com](http://www.midrange.com) lists. I would try [MIDRANGE-L](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/midrange-l) or [System i dotNet](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/systemidotnet).

Comment: We can only consistenly duplicate this by opening a connection, making a query then closing the connection. Then killing the correspending Job. Finally open a new connection and attempt the query again. It will fail with "Communication Error".   This might not be related, but I think the key to this all is the jobs ending while the client thinks they exist...

Comment: Are you getting any job logs or dumps? Check the user you are logging in as and QUSER (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error because my password had expired and I changed it, but I forgot to update my connection strings in my .config files. Therefore, my user was disabled after three (programmatic) attempts to login with the old password.

I realized this when I tried to acess the server using Query Tool and it told me my user was disabled even though I entered the new password. It was my bad, but the error message was not really informative...